# Exclude folders and files in Laravel Mix and Webpack

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

How do I exclude specific folders and files to be uploaded to S3 using Laravel Mix and Webpack?

I tried this solution https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-mix-upload-files-to-s3 and https://medium.com/@avosalmon/cache-busting-using-laravel-mix-and-cloudfront-s3-eb222b569f88 but it's not doing what I want to do.

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const S3Plugin = require('webpack-s3-plugin');
require('dotenv').config();

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

let webpackPlugins = [];

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    webpackPlugins = [
        new S3Plugin({
            include: /.*\.(css|js|ico|jpg|png)$/,
            s3Options: {
                accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
                region: process.env.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION,
                // endpoint: process.env.AWS_ENDPOINT,
            },
            s3UploadOptions: {
                Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
                CacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000'
            },
            directory: 'public',
        })
    ];
}

mix.js('resources/js/alpine.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/choices.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/clipboard.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/notyf.js', 'public/js');

mix.postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require("tailwindcss"),
    ]);

mix.disableSuccessNotifications();

mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: webpackPlugins
});

mix.version();
```

When I run this code, it uploads all contents and folders with css, js, ico, jpg and png files. However, I want to exclude specific folder regardless if it contains (css, js, ico, jpg and png) files.

Example folders inside the public directory

- avatars (needs to be excluded regardless of the file types inside)
- css
- images
- js
- index.php (excluded)
- favicon.ico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can use `CopyWebpackPlugin` to move your files from the build/static directory, to your compiled destination. You don't need to put your files in the source directory, but in a folder that you copy:

https://laravel-mix.com/docs/4.0/copying-files